# Yii2 Unknown Property Exception in Server

Tags: php, yii2

I have a view displaying a grid view for a particular model. In my local machine, it's working well but when I deploy the application to another server, an attribute is not found hence the Unknown Property Exception. When I look at the code though, the attribute is there.

Any ideas?

Here is the model class code: http://codebin.org/view/f0a713c1

The view code:

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [

    [
        'attribute' => 'is_condemned',
        'label' => 'Condemned',
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
        'falseLabel' => 'Active',
        'trueLabel' => 'Condemned'
    ],
],
// set your toolbar
'toolbar' => [
    ['content' =>
        Html::a(FA::icon('plus') . ' Add', ['/equipment/default/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])
    ],
    '{export}',
    '{toggleData}',
],
// set export properties
'export' => [
    'fontAwesome' => true,
    'filename' => 'equipment-export-'.time(),
    'exportConfig' => [
        'html' => ['showCaption' => FALSE],
        'pdf' => ['showCaption' => FALSE],
    ],
],
'bordered' => TRUE,
'striped' => TRUE,
'condensed' => TRUE,
'responsive' => TRUE,
'hover' => TRUE,
'showPageSummary' => TRUE,
'panel' => [
    'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
    'heading' => '',
],
'persistResize' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Your machine is windows or Unix? and the server?

Comment: I'm using OSX. Funny thing is that when I tried it on another machine running OSX, it also works. Doesn't work on Ubuntu and Windows though.

Comment: The server is 5.5. My local version is 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working was that the model class being imported was in lowercase. Apparently, I entered the wrong value in gii. It was just in the other servers that it was case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Could be either a problem with case (Uppercase, lowercase) in the namespace or in the class name or backslash path problem (`/`, `\`). In this case the class is not found and Yii shows this message.

Comment: I suspect that may be the case. Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Not the Class / Model code but the view / gridview code please

Comment: why not  'class' => '\kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',

Comment: Show my the use and the namespace (the header of the file)

Comment: This is the header of the view file,

   `use kartik\grid\GridView;`
   `use rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\FA;`
   `use yii\helpers\Html;`

Comment: Please could you show the attribute an the error message

Comment: It's the is_condemned attribute.

Comment: You Use a database ?, Are you sure that the servers that use Ubuntu and Windows the database is updated and the name of the field matches?